# JavaScript: Grouping Objects w/ Similar Attributes

Tags: javascript

I have an array of JavaScript objects, that look something like this.

```
[ { name: "A", value: 50 },
  { name: "B", value: 20 }, 
  { name: "C", value: 30 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 40 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 50 }, 
  { name: "B", value: 70 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 10 }, 
  { name: "C", value: 50 } ]
```

I want to loop through this array and remove any duplicate objects of the same name, while adding their values together. In basic terms:

```
[ { name: "A", value: 200 },
  { name: "B", value: 90  }, 
  { name: "C", value: 80  } ]
```

I have an idea of how to go about this, pseudo-code:

```
for each object Obj in array A
    current = Obj
    for(i = (Obj's index + 1); i < A.length; i++)
        if(A[i].name = Obj.name) 
            Obj.value += A[i].value
            delete A[i]
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```

I feel this is very inefficient. Is there any better way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Note that for simplicity the sums are gathered as an associative array (grouped by `name`) and then the values retrieved to match your expected result.

```js
var arr = [ { name: "A", value: 50 },
  { name: "B", value: 20 }, 
  { name: "C", value: 30 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 40 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 50 }, 
  { name: "B", value: 70 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 10 }, 
  { name: "C", value: 50 } ];

var sums = arr.reduce(function (acc, curr) { 
  if(acc[curr.name]) {
    acc[curr.name].value += curr.value;
  } else {
    acc[curr.name] = curr;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

var res = Object.keys(sums).map(function (key) {
    return sums[key];
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi @Tomasz Pluskiewicz, I think you made a mistake in your code. This isn't calculating the sum, it is only obtaining the first value.

Comment: Yeah, I changed from my initial code and instead of `+=` there was `+`. Thanks for spotting this

Answer (score 3):

I would use a temporary object as an intermediary state, and then create a new array based on that object:

```js
var arr = [ { name: "A", value: 50 },
  { name: "B", value: 20 }, 
  { name: "C", value: 30 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 40 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 50 }, 
  { name: "B", value: 70 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 10 }, 
  { name: "C", value: 50 } ];

var tempObj = arr.reduce(function (newObj, obj) {
    if (newObj[obj.name]) {
        newObj[obj.name] += obj.value;
    } else {
        newObj[obj.name] = obj.value;
    }
    return newObj;
}, {});

console.log(tempObj);

var result = [];

for (var i in tempObj) {
    result.push({
        name: i,
        value: tempObj[i]
    });
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `forEach()` loop and `thisArg` parameter.

```js
var data = [ { name: "A", value: 50 },
  { name: "B", value: 20 }, 
  { name: "C", value: 30 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 40 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 50 }, 
  { name: "B", value: 70 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 10 }, 
  { name: "C", value: 50 } ];
  
var result = [];
data.forEach(function(e) {
  if (!this[e.name]) {
    this[e.name] = e;
    result.push(this[e.name]);
  } else {
    this[e.name].value += e.value;
  }
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: The most concise answer! Thank you so much! :) I have another question, if I had multiple values "value1: 40, value2: 50" do I just copy the line inside the "else" statement and make it 
`this[e.name].value1 += e.value1; 
this[e.name].value2 += e.value2;`?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary "associative array" and iterate through the array of objects like

```
var temp = [];
for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    temp[A[i].name] += A[i].value;
}
A = temp;
```

If you're trying to keep `A` as an actual array, then look at @TAGraves answer for the extra bit to convert it into an actual array.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `reduce` and object-based indexing:

```js
var arr = [ { name: "A", value: 50 },
  { name: "B", value: 20 }, 
  { name: "C", value: 30 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 40 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 50 }, 
  { name: "B", value: 70 }, 
  { name: "A", value: 10 }, 
  { name: "C", value: 50 } ]

var accumulated = arr.reduce(function(accumulator, element) {
     var currentValue = accumulator[element.name];
     if(currentValue !== undefined) {
         accumulator[element.name] = currentValue + element.value;
     } else {
         accumulator[element.name] = element.value;
     }
     return accumulator;
}, {})

var result = Object.keys(accumulated).map(function(k) {return {name: k, value: accumulated[k]}})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

What language is this? this ain't JS.

in JS I would write it like that:

```
array = array.filter(function(item){
    //check wether there's already an cached item for this name
    if(item.name in this){
        //then add the value to the cached item
        this[item.name].value += item.value;
        //and remove the current item from the result
        return false;
    }else{
        //otherwise cache this item
        this[item.name] = item;
        //and keep it in the result
        return true;
    }
}, {/* abusing `this` as a cache */});
```

Comment: If you reread my post, you'll see that I mentioned that it was pseudocode. Thanks though.